# Give permission to upload to drive account to another user

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm developing a feature in my app where user needs to give access to his google drive account to another user so the second can upload files to drive.

I have been searching `google drive android api` and also checked out the [demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) but I can't find anything relative to what I want.

Is this something that's doable and if yes then what do  I need from the api to create it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to fully give access to your google Drive is to share your password, which isn't something you would want. What you can do is share a folder where the other user can move files in and out.

You do this by using [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create), setting the type to "user" and providing the email of that user. You can check code samples in [Sharing Files in Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing):

```
Permission userPermission = new Permission()
        .setType("user")
        .setRole("writer")
        .setEmailAddress("example@appsrocks.com");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, userPermission)
        .setFields("id")
        .queue(batch, callback);

Permission domainPermission = new Permission()
        .setType("domain")
        .setRole("reader")
        .setDomain("appsrocks.com");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, domainPermission)
        .setFields("id")
        .queue(batch, callback);
```

You can read this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/J43TnTxcpuM) which seems to talk about the same issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Haven't tried it yet but I think your answer is on the right track that's why I've accepted it.